# What is 'size' in pymongo's Cursor.batch_size(size)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

From version 1.9, pymongo added the option to change the batch size of a cursor operation See [description here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.batch_size).

But they don't say anywhere what this size is supposed to mean. Is this the number of records to fetch at a time? Or is this absolute size?

Also, what is the default size for the cursor? I checked `__dict__` for the Cursor, and it says batch_size is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The batch size refers to the number of results that are retrieved with the cursor before issuing a getMore message to fetch more results. The default is 101 documents.

Edit:
Sorry, I should clarify - the default is actually set by the server, but as of the current latest release it is 101.

Comment: On getmores (i.e. subsequent roundtrips after the first) there is no 101 document default limit, the server will return up to about 4MB worth of documents at a time.

Comment: @dcrosta - but the subsequent getmores do honor the batch_size that is set right? For e.g. if batch_size is set to 1000 and that makes it more than 4MB, would it still be limited to 4MB or would it fetch all 1000?

Comment: @Akash Mongo will respond to either a query or getmore once the accumulated documents to return are greater than or equal to the smallest of 4MB, `batch_size` or `limit`, or 101 documents (only in the case of the initial query with no `batch_size` or `limit` set).